# please help me debug this php code

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

Morning All,

I have a form that I am using to add multiple rows into a database at once. It all seems to be working fine, except for the checkboxes. There is one checkbox for each form row. Regardless of what order the checkboxes are ticked, the results are always returned in the same order after being submitted.

Here is the main part of the form that matters:

```
<tr>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='rowid[]' value='".$row."' style='display:none;' />
<input type='text' name='ref[]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='obs[]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='act[]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border' align='center'>
<input type='checkbox' name='comp[]' value='Yes' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='compby[]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='compdate[]' id='completeddate".$row."' class='completeddate' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
</tr>
```

This form gets submitted, and my PHP code deals with it. You can see that the very first input, is the ID of the row of the form. This is a hidden field and the value is incremented by one for each row that is displayed in the form.

Once the form is submitted, I use the below PHP to get deal with each row, one at a time

```
foreach($_POST['rowid'] as $key=>$rowid) {
```

This should basically say that for a rowid, the rest of the inputs are associated, until it gets to the next rowid.

If I were to then print say

```
echo $_POST['ref'][$key];
```

I will get the reference for the first row, and then once the loop completes and prints it again, I will get the reference for the second row, and so on.

However, if I were to put

```
echo $_POST['comp'][$key];
```

Then this is where it breaks.

Let's say for example, that for each row I ticked the checkboxes in this order:

```
row 1, tick, row 2, untick, row 3, tick
```

If I then let the loop print out all of the checkbox values, it will display

```
'Yes', 'Yes', ''
```

But it should be in this order

```
'Yes', '', 'Yes'
```

Is this because the checkbox is normal an array anyway, and I am then putting this into another array by giving it a name of comp[]?

Is there anyway around this issue, or would I be better off having radio buttons, one for yes, and one for no?

Many thanks

Eds

Comment: Uhhhh... `'rowid[]' != 'rowid'`

Comment: use `print_r($_POST)` after you click on Submit and show us the result ...

Comment: when you submit form then check boxes will only send checked values... so if you count number of $_POST['comp'] you will see that number are equal to numbers checked in your form before you submit not the number of checkboxes.... you can have different name for each check box line comp_1 or something similar..

Comment: so here is the part of the print_r referencing the checkbox array     [comp] => Array ( [0] => Yes [1] => Yes )

Comment: So I am assuming that as one of the checkboxes doesnt have a value, it does not add it to the array at all? In which case, I would need to have a yes and a no checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to create a technical hidden field in a form is to use the `hidden` type. Anyway, you don't need this field here. Instead, use `$row` in all fields to properly identify them:

```
<tr>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='ref[<?php echo $row; ?>]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='obs[<?php echo $row; ?>]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='act[<?php echo $row; ?>]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border' align='center'>
<input type='checkbox' name='comp[<?php echo $row; ?>]' value='Yes' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='compby[<?php echo $row; ?>]' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
<td class='border'>
<input type='text' name='compdate[<?php echo $row; ?>]' id='completeddate<?php echo $row; ?>' class='completeddate' style='width:100%;' />
</td>
</tr>
```

Change the loop (the `rowid` field no longer exists). You may loop on any of your `text` fields, since they will be submitted even if empty (contrary to checkboxes fields, that are submitted only when checked):

```
foreach($_POST['ref'] as $key => $rowid) {
```

Check your PHP code, there may be more things to update.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think this will ultimately be the way I should go!

Answer (score 1):

Try subscripting the array indices. I.e. make it explicit which `comp[]` belongs to what row by changing it to `comp[$row]`. The point is that unchecked boxes are not sent, so when not all boxes are checked you have only 2 `comp[]` elements in the request and you can't tell to which row they belong.

BTW you should have gotten a warning when accessing `$_POST['comp'][$key]` for that last (non-existent) `$key`. If not, enable all warnings. Warnings are generally very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Adding a number into the checkbox array (comp[]), will work as a quick and dirty way of getting done what I need.

Comment: Sorry, this is basically the same as the answer I accepted, so either answer could have been accepted. I will look into turning on warnings though. Thanks

Comment: @Eds yes indeed, but not just "a number ... quick&dirty", but the actual row id. NP about the accept although I was 7 minutes earlier ;-)

Comment: Haha yes sorry. I think it was just because Jocelyn mentioned putting $row into the input names. Don't worry, i'll accept your answer next time :D